In QT, using QWindow::fromWinId to embed Chrome, keyboard input is not available in Chrome
In QT 6.4.2, using QWindow::fromWinId and QWidget::createWindowContainer to embed Chrome. However, after embedding, it is found that Chrome cannot use keyboard data (but the mouse can). The same code, when embedding Firefox, works just fine. Does anyone know how to handle this? The code is as follows:
WId m_wid = (WId)FindWindow(L"Chrome_WidgetWin_1",L"百度一下，你就知道 - Google Chrome");//第一个参数xxx为调用的exe的类名；第二个xxx参数为调用的exe的标题名。
    //WId m_wid = (WId)FindWindow(L"MozillaWindowClass",L"百度一下，你就知道 — Mozilla Firefox");//第一个参数xxx为调用的exe的类名；第二个xxx参数为调用的exe的标题名。

    MouseTrackingWindow *M_WINDOW = (MouseTrackingWindow *)QWindow::fromWinId(m_wid);
    M_WINDOW->setFlags(M_WINDOW->flags() | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::WindowTitleHint);
    MyWidget *childWidget =(MyWidget*)QWidget::createWindowContainer(M_WINDOW,this);//创建新的widget
    ui->horizontalLayout->addWidget(childWidget);//将widget窗口加入到主界面布局中
    childWidget->setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);
    childWidget->show();

embeded chrome connot input by keyboard

Keyboard focus is one of the many possible problems of using createWindowContainer, and it's also clearly explained in the documentation. Also note that the main purpose of that feature is to embed windows of other Qt based processes. Using it for completely foreign windows is unsupported and unreliable (it may work on one system and not on another).

Indeed, using createWindowContainer to embed Chrome can lead to unpredictable behavior, but for my application, it is the most convenient solution.However, similarly, using Firefox presents no issues.
Some suggestions?

Chrome and Firefox are based on their own, different toolkits. The fact that embedding one works doesn't mean that the other should. The only suggestion is to try to figure out the focus handling (check the QWindow docs and the Qt sources); yet, as said, the embedding non Qt programs is not guaranteed, it works in unexpected ways depending on the program and its toolkit, and even if you find a way, it may stop working if the program is upgraded (because they changed something in its user input implementation), and the fact that it works for you does not ensure that it will for others.
